# CSS3 Drop Down Menu & iOS issues

Tags: ios, css, css-transitions

I'm attempting to make a drop down navigation menu with some CSS3 transitions. However, when using visibility hidden/visible, iOS doesn't display the drop down (it just goes to the link). If I use display none/block, iOS will display the drop down menu on the first click of the parent element, but the transitions don't work in any browsers.

Is there a way to get these transitions to function correctly in browsers and the drop-downs to work in iOS without using javascript?

Drop down doesn't work in iOS:

```
nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; left: 0; top: 50px; z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; top: 40px; }
```

Transitions don't work in browsers:

```
nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute; display: none; opacity: 0; left: 0; top: 50px; z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul { display: block; opacity: 1; top: 40px; }
```

Comment: By iOS do you mean Mobile Safari? Why are you trying to rely on :hover for a touch device (it's unpredictable)? I see that you don't want to use JS but it allows you to be a lot more precise with events. In my opinion you should use a Javascript click event to display and hide things and suppress the link action with event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about this some more I found documentation that I hadn't seen before -- some of the weirdness you're experiencing might be because you are attaching behavior to a pseudo-element on something that isn't interactive by default (only anchors and form elements are clickable).

[http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html](https://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html)

(Ignore my original comment about event.preventDefault...I forgot you were working with list items instead of anchors.)

I do, however, still think JS is the best approach since you can be very specific about events attached to any kind of element. You can just apply a CSS class and it will use the transition properties you already specified.

Like this:

```
// CSS
nav ul li > ul.visible { display: block; opacity: 1; top: 40px; }

// JS
// you could bind mouseover/out here too if you want it to work on both desktop & mobile
$('nav ul li').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

If you want to be extra awesome you could make it keyboard accessible by adding `tabIndex="0"` to the list items :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. Essentially ios does not bind the click to the hover for anything that is display:block/none or visibility:hidden/visible. So you need to just "hide" the dropdown using the "left" to compensate for <=ie8 that does not support opacity.

So essentially use your 2nd example with a minor tweak:

```
nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute; opacity: 0; left: -888em; top: 50px; z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .35s ease-in-out, top .35s ease-in-out;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {opacity: 1; top: 40px; left:0;}
```

Then just be sure not to use "all" in your transitions or it will animate the left attribute as well :)
The only issue with this method is that your transitions will only work on the way in not the way out.